# Why Spatial index not used by MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a problem in mysql. i created a table for some polygons and added index but index not used when i selecting data
this is my table for storing polygons

```
CREATE TABLE road_polygon (
id bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  road_polygon polygon NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  SPATIAL INDEX (road_polygon)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

When I query data does not use index. i checked the Mysql documentation and many post but does not resolve, also i tried to change MyIsam not working

```
explain  
    select id, road_polygon 
    from road_polygon 
    where st_contains(road_polygon, POINT(32.027856, 36.803250));

id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  road_polygon    NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    77  100.00  Using where
```

also i'm use Mysql 8.0.12 InnoDb.

Please any help how to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to show the output of the `explain` command?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  5.7 and 8.0 use the Boost.geometry code which is light years past what was in earlier versions

Comment: thank you.I updated the question also i am using Mysql 8.0.12

Comment: it might not use the indexes because there are not many rows in the table and its faster to do a full table scan to search the polygons' POINT. The real question is : Is the performance good or bad?

Comment: @ThomasG thats not true because i added more than 200,000 rows but it seems that is not using index. and for larger dataset it will be slow. here the explain query again 


```
    id select_type table partitions type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
    1 SIMPLE road_polygon NULL ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 230038 100.00 Using where
```

Comment: Right. But we didnt know it. You should add this information to your question, along with the explain plan

Comment: You right. Thanks for your replay first time I forget to add it.

Comment: @ThomasG is there any solution ? I realy need it to work.

Comment: did you find the solution? I am stuck at the same problem