# MySQL 5.7 cannot get spatial index to be used

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, spatial

```
CREATE TABLE zip_polygons_new(
    zipcode MEDIUMINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    zip_polygon MULTIPOLYGON NOT NULL,
    spatial index (zip_polygon)
);

EXPLAIN 
SELECT zipcode
FROM zip_polygons_new zp
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(zp.zip_polygon, ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(-99.24012 19.53285)'));
```

I always get:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | zp |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 26376 | 100.0 | Using where |

I've tried:

- both InnoDB and MyIsam.
- Several spacial functions (e.g. MBRCONTAINS, ST_CONTAINS).
- putting an equality to 1 on RHS of WHERE clause.

Already checked:
MySQL documentation
[Mysql Spatial index unused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388990/mysql-spatial-index-unused)
[Why Spatial index not used by MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55055297/why-spatial-index-not-used-by-mysql)

What am I missing to be able to use the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I did not realized I had mysql@8 running, when switching back to mysql@5.7 the index is now used.

So the issue was on mysql@8, as my question was related to mysql@5.7 I consider it self-answered.  Probably the issue is that mysql@8 expects an explicit SRID to use the spatial index while mysql@5.7 does not.